# getting the view of item on which context menu item has been called

Tags: android, textview, contextmenu

I am creating a list of TextView on which I am creating a context menu. However how do I know on which TextView the context menu was called?

Here is my code
http://snipt.org/vfyj7

Comment: The above code above is crashing. But I am sure experts will be able to tell the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all necessary information from MenuItem:


`AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();`


item.position contains selected item position.

Comment: I can get the menu item but I want the widget which is a list of multiple text view. On any text view it could be called so how do I know which TextView not menu item the context menu was originally created?

Comment: For example if I have text1 text2 text3, and I long pressed on text 2 and I get menu 1 menu 2 menu3. If I select menu 2 , I can fetch information that menu 2 was selected. But how do I know text 2 was selected?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular override for your activity, you can get the id of the textView that was clicked and then do necessary operations based on the textView.

```
  @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

        if(item.getItemId()==R.id.textView1) {
       //do something with 1st textview
     }    
     else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.textView2) {
      //do something with textview 2
    } and so on....
    }
```

Comment: This sort of worked, but it always returns id of first text view for some reason.

Comment: You have to do a comparison using if..else or switch statements to compare IDs. Else only 1st id will be returned. See my modified code